# FMPP: How to set a Freemarker variable from a BeanShell script

Tags: freemarker, beanshell, fmpp

Is it possible to set one or more freemarker variable in a case like:

```
<#assign test=pp.loadData('eval', '
a="test1";
b="test2";
return "test";')>
```

and having access to a and b in the freemarker script ?

Comment: You can set it in the config.fmpp file. Can you do it that way?

Comment: What i want to do is to parse a string in bsh and decompose it into several freemarker variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it can't be done without writing a custom `DataLoader`. I'm saying "guess" because maybe I don't know about a *BeanShell* trick. The closest I could get is using `return this.namespace;` and then `${test.getVariable('a')}`. This is too verbose of course.

Update:
Actually, the following horror is even closer:

```
<#assign test=pp.loadData('eval', '
    a="test1";
    b="test2";

    // This should be factored out into a common function somehow
    ns = this.namespace;
    vars = new HashMap();
    for (name : ns.getVariableNames()) {
      vars.put(name, ns.getVariable(name));
    }
    return vars;
')>

${test.a}
```

Comment: ok, thank you, it suits me. It is not for a production environment.